# How can I read and write data for HKUnit for liter() type?

Tags: swift, healthkit

I'm working on an app that allows me to see a person's water consumption, but I am not able to access `HealthKit` data. How do I read and write `.liter()` data?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HKUnit.liter()` returns an object that is used for interpreting measurements, and is not a HealthKit data type itself. If you want write water consumption you'll need to create instances of `HKQuantitySample` with the type `HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryWater`. To read this data from HealthKit, I recommend using `HKStatisticsQuery` or `HKStatisticsCollectionQuery` to query aggregate values for particular time ranges. For examples of how to use these APIs, there is documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkstatisticsquery) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkstatisticscollectionquery).